# Usage of ...から参加し

Tags: meaning

> この会議には第2回から参加し、「今回のテーマは"システムズ×ひろげる"。

I'm having problems understanding the meaning of から参加し in the above sentence. Is it something like "having participated since the 2nd conference"?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

This 「から」 is a `Case particle` meaning "**from** or **since**," which is used when you want to tell a spacial or time/sequential *starting point.*

- 東京{とうきょう} *から* -> **FROM** Tokyo (Spatial)
- 7時{じ} *から* -> **FROM/SINCE** 7 (Time)
- 3番目{ばんめ} *から* -> **FROM/SINCE** 3rd (Sequential, This case)

So, as you guessed, 「から参加し」 in this context is interpreted as "... participate from ..." or "... participate since ..."
In this specific case, we don't know when this "participation streak" ends, so we get to choose `since`.